# Local wordpress developement with instant edits

Tags: css, wordpress, ide, local

I currently have a simple wordpress site staged on Siteground.  Rather than use the Editor native to Wordpress, I use Sublime text to edit my child css and function files.  Is there a way to view style edits WITHOUT having to push these edits back to the server and refresh the page?
To clarify, if I create a simple site that is comprised of a index.html and main.css page, when working in Sublime, obviously I can open the .html page in a browser to view edits.  Is there an equivalent way to see changes to wordpress pages before I 'push' my edits to the server, and refresh the page?  Is developing locally the best way to achieve this? 
Thank you.

Comment: It's not wordpress that requires you to push your changes to the server, but the fact that it's remote. I don't use Sublime, but most IDE's have a way to automatically upload changes on a remote server, when detected. Similarly, you could install WP on local. Typically you develop on local and only push it on remote when happy.

Comment: Please note questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu thank you!  That makes sense and I totally understand the distinction between remote/local in those terms.  I guess what I mean is - say I have the entire Wordpress site file hierarchy on my computer.  Is there a single file (the index.html equivalent in my example above) that I can open locally to view changes? Or do I need to go through the entire process of locally installing a WP server to do that?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have the entire website on local. What matters is: are you able to view it on local? You need \*amp setup (Apache + MySQL + php) installed and running. Without those, you can't view your website locally, therefore you can't view your changes locally and you need to upload them on remote, which has all of the above.